# Sorting Details Page MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting

I cant figured out how perform sort in a details page. I have a classic page with list of order and for each row i have a actionlink to return details view of that order. 
i try this

```
public ActionResult Details(int? anno,int? nr, string centro, string sortOrder)
        {
            ViewBag.Codice = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ?  "Articolo_desc" : "";

            if (anno == null && nr == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(centro))
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            else
            {
                string s = "anno=" + Request.QueryString["anno"] + "&nr=" + Request.QueryString["nr"] + "&centro=" + Request.QueryString["centro"];
                ViewBag.search = s.Replace("search=", "").Replace("%3D", "=");
            }

            var righe = from d in db.DETAILS
                        where d.Anno == anno && d.Num == nr && d.Centro == centro
                        select new DetailsOrdersView
                        {
                            Articolo = r.Codice,
                            ...
                        };

            if (righe == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            switch(sortOrder)
            {
                case "Articolo_desc":
                    righe = righe.OrderByDescending(i => i.Articolo);
                    break;
                default:
                    righe = righe.OrderBy(i => i.Articolo);
                    break;
            }

            return View(righe);
        }
    }
```

and in details view

```
@Html.ActionLink("codice","Details", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.Codice, ViewBag.search })
```

but i on sorting I get bad request and this is the route
Orders/Details?sortOrder=Articolo_desc&search=anno%3D2017%26nr%3D6%26centro%3D1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("codice", "Details", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.Codice, anno = ViewBag.Anno, centro = ViewBag.Centro , nr= ViewBag.Numero })
```

i solved as above